# How to add two variable in bash?

Tags: bash

I would like to add two variable in bash, but its not work, i got this error: ")invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ,,

Here is my code:

```
FILE=adat2.txt
let i=0
declare -A codeDict
while IFS=$'\n' read -r line;
do
     #echo "$line"
     IFS=$' ' read -a STR_ARRAY <<< "${line}"
     #echo "code: ${STR_ARRAY[2]} db: ${STR_ARRAY[3]}"
     if [ -z "${codeDict["${STR_ARRAY[2]}"]+xxx}" ]
     then
          echo "codeDict not contains ${STR_ARRAY[2]}"
          codeDict[${STR_ARRAY[2]}]=${STR_ARRAY[3]}
     else
          summa=$((${codeDict[${STR_ARRAY[2]}]}+${STR_ARRAY[3]}))
          echo "summa value: $summa"
     fi
done < $FILE
```

Comment: What are `${STR_ARRAY[2]}`, `${STR_ARRAY[3]}`, and `${codeDict[${STR_ARRAY[2]}]}` when this happens?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Are you using `sh` instead of `bash` to run this? Maybe add a `#!/bin/bash` shebang.

Comment: Though the error message looks more like maybe you have DOS line endings. See the [bash tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) for troubleshooting tips.

Comment: i read data from file, and the file line look like this: "2014.01.02 19:40 19789 3"
in STR_ARRAY[2] i have the "19789" number
in STR_ARRAY[3] i have the "3" number
and the codeDict is an associate array with these data: [19789][3]
if i echo STR_ARRAY[3], STR_ARRAY[2] and codeDict[${STR_ARRAY[2]}] i got the values, but i cant add them

Comment: @tripleee i have #!/bin/bash in my file at the first line

Comment: @Cyrus the site said it all looks good

Comment: So does the input file have correct line endings?

Comment: i dont know the line endings, how can i check?

Comment: The `IFS` setting is redundant; `read` only reads a single `\n`-terminated line at a time, so the value of `line` won't contain any newlines to split.

Comment: You don't actually need an array. You can use something like `read v1 v2 key value` instead. You should probably post a question describing what you are trying to do, because it seems there is a far simpler solution compared to your current code.

Comment: Sigh. Repeat: Click the link I [already provided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30356788/how-to-add-two-variable-in-bash#comment48805713_30356788) once. Read the  instructions there.

Comment: Try without arrays first. Something like  `(( summa = field2 + field3 ))`

Comment: fix line-endings with `dos2unix file1 file2 file3 ..`. It can't hurt to run it and may eliminate a whole class of error from debugging process. Good luck.